# How can I show a currently Board in tic tac toe in Mips

Tags: assembly, mips, tic-tac-toe

I want to display currentely board status with simple code.
So I want to bring .byte Board with drawBoard So after excute this can be showed

For example

```
.data
 .globl main
     board:
    .byte 'O', ' ', ' ',
          ' ', 'X', 'O',
          'O', ' ', 'X'

  .globl drawBoard
    
     row: .asciiz "   |   |   \n"
     col: .asciiz "---|---|--- \n"
     Spieler1: .asciiz "O"
     Spieler2: .asciiz "X"


 .text
 
  main:
  
   la $a0 board
   jal drawBoard
   li $v0 10
   syscall
 
     drawBoard:
        li $v0, 4
    la $a0, row
    syscall 
    la $a0, row
    syscall
    la $a0, col
    syscall
    la $a0, row
    syscall 
    la $a0, col
    syscall
    la $a0, row
    syscall
    la $a0, row
    syscall
    
    
    jr $ra
```

With this code just

```
   |   |   
   |   |   
---|---|--- 
   |   |   
---|---|--- 
   |   |   
   |   |
```

this was showed

but I expected

```
   |   |   
 O |   |   
---|---|--- 
   | X | O 
---|---|--- 
 O |   | X
   |   |
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: You'd have to store `'O'` or `'X'` characters into your row string before printing it, if you want it something other than spaces.  IDK why you'd expect that code to have printed the final output with X and O in it; perhaps you mean *desired*?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. I mean, I want to draw a Board and then with board .byte to show the status of board. I'm not sure, I explained correctly So with drawBoard should can show a result with any board: byte.

Comment: One obvious issue is that your `board` array/string isn't terminated by a NUL-character (i.e. a byte with the value 0). But aside from that, the `print_string` system call has no idea that you want to overlay one string on top of another. It will start printing at the position where the previous print stopped. I'm not sure if any of the commonly used MIPS simulators have system calls for moving the text cursor.

Comment: You code is not broken, it is incomplete.  It doesn't need fixing, it needs finishing.

Comment: @Michael: Last time someone asked, MARS / SPIM do not have any cursor-movement stuff.  Hopefully `board:` is just intended as game-state, not for printing.  Note that it doesn't have spaces or newline.  So yeah, just copy it into the right offsets in the board string.